# Error with bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm getting the following error when running bundle install via rvm:

```
There was an error while trying to write to `/opt/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

Any solution ??

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X Sierra

Comment: try `sudo bundle install`

Comment: I don't want to use bundle with sudo. I've never done that. I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: can you show return for `rvm list` ? iti seems like you use `system` ruby

Comment: i'm not using system ruby.

Comment: Gem::FilePermissionError: You don't have write permissions for the /opt/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0 directory.
An error occurred while installing aasm (3.0.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install aasm -v '3.0.8'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: this directory not even exists.

Comment: Maybe that directory doesn't exist because bundler is trying to create it. Out of curiosity, what user are you logged in as? Bundler should be installing things under the `/usr/local` hierarchy, and not `/opt`. In fact, there's no top level `/opt` directory at all -- it's a subdirectory under `/usr/local`, where third party apps store data.

Comment: Run `rvm info` and check your paths. You may not be initializing rvm properly (e.g. not in a login shell).